# Fun project: PHP foreach loop and Scraping

Tags: php, loops, foreach, screen-scraping

I'm creating a members card that displays a list of members that are scraped from their profile urls and outputs as an image.

The best way to describe what i'm trying to accomplish is to show you:

[This is what i'm trying to do.](http://lifeofstrange.com/scrape/output.jpg)

The players alias, level and rank are scraped from there profile using the [Simple HTML DOM Parser.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

This is what i have managed to achieve so far using the following code:

[My Scraping Attempt](http://lifeofstrange.com/scrape/image.php)

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function extract_numbers($string) {
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);
    return $match[0];
}

function scraping_uberstrike($url) {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($url);



 // Find rank, level and xp
    $string =  $html->find("h2 p", 0)->innertext;
    $numbers_array = extract_numbers($string);

// get name
$ret['Alias'] = $html->find('span[id="uberstrikeUserName"]', 0)->innertext;

// get level
$ret['Level'] = $numbers_array['1'];

// get rank
$ret['Rank'] = $numbers_array['0'];

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

return $ret;
}
```

// URLS to Scrape

```
$links = array (
   'http://uberstrike.cmune.com/CommonChannel/Profile?cmid=4758758&channelType=WebPortal&appCallbackUrl=http%3a%2f%2fuberstrike.cmune.com%2fProfile',
   'http://uberstrike.cmune.com/CommonChannel/Profile?cmid=5909289&channelType=WebPortal&appCallbackUrl=http%3a%2f%2fuberstrike.cmune.com%2fProfile'
 );

$image = imagecreatefrompng("eQ.png");
$color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 203,203,203);
$shadow = ImageColorAllocate($image, 25,25,25);
$font = "ColabBol.otf";

$a=2;
$b=1;

// Outputs the scrape

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $ret = scraping_uberstrike($link);
        foreach($ret as $k=>$v) {

          $a = $a + 40;
          $b = $b + 40;
            imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 106,  $a, $shadow, $font, $v);
            imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 105, $b, $color, $font, $v);
        }
} 

header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Notice how the players details are positioned using the foreach loop, i'm having difficulty in getting the output as the same as the jpg i'm trying to do.

There must be something wrong or a different method to use for the foreach loop to display the details correctly.

I have put all the necessary files in a zip archive if this will help you understand my code.

http://lifeofstrange.com/scrape/scrape.zip

I hope i have made this clear.

And looking forward to your solutions.

Thankyou :)

Comment: Instead of using `$a` & `$b` you should associate with what it does `y-ordinate`, so like `$vert` this will help you. As that value is in pixels the incrementing value `40px` is too small and also the initialization of only `$a=2` , thats why its placement is at the top.

Comment: Hi Lawrence, i want to be able to use the "imagettftext" function in the foreach loop for the different scraping, such as the alias should  have a imagettftext, level and rank so on, at the moment the imagettftext is used for all of the scraped info for each member

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know what your code is giving as output that is not the same as "some_path/output.jpg".  You are asking too much for strangers to unzip files and visit at offsite URLs and such.   Try to come up with a demonstration of your problem using integers or limit the question to one particular graphics element.

A good place to break up your problem is between the data gathering and data output portions.  Don't make a helpful passerby read through a bunch of file_get() and regexs if that is not your trouble area. Separating input and output would help you program structure also.

Number one rule of programming, tackle your data structure first, then go for the pretty stuff. In your case that means get you program so you can read and print 'Alias', 'Level', and 'Rank' as simple scalars in some kind of format and then work on the graphics with some kind of sample data set.  Combining the two working parts later is a lot easier that a mess of spagettios.

These two line look strange to me:

```
        imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 106,  $a, $shadow, $font, $v);
        imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 105, $b, $color, $font, $v);
```

They are separated by one pixel in x and y. Is this what you wanted? Also size and angle are supposed to be floats ( I know not PHP and whether it will cast these )  at least use "... 14.0, 0.0,..."

That's all the help I can offer, as I said, I know not PHP.